# Ruby array methods for locating based on an object's attribute?

Tags: ruby, arrays, syntax

Say I have a Ruby class, `Flight`. `Flight` has an `attr_accessor :key` on it. If there's an array of instances of this class: `flights = [flight1, flight2, flight3]`, I have a "target key", say "2jf345", and I want to find a flight based on it's key, from that array - what sort of code should I use?

This is the code I was going to use:

`flights[flights.map { |s| s.key }.index(target_key)]`

But it seems like with Ruby, there should be a simpler way. Also, the code above returns an error for me - `` `[]': no implicit conversion from nil to integer (TypeError) ``. I assume this means that it's not returning an index at all.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I answered a very similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974249/finding-first-value-in-an-array-which-does-not-have-a-specific-value/7974278#7974278) a few days ago.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can just use `find` to get the Flight object, instead of trying to use `index` to get the index:

```
flights.find {|s| s.key == target_key }
```

However your error message suggests that `index(target_key)` returns `nil`, which means that you don't actually have a flight with the key you're looking for, which means that `find` will return `nil` as well.

Comment: Stupid question, but is there a reason the method isn't shown in the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html)?

Comment: @Walter: It's in the docs for Enumerable, not Array, because that's where it's inherited from (same for `map`, `select`, `inject` and most other important higher-order methods).

Comment: Thanks for the help, feeling a bit slow today haha.